# Pie chart not working using angular and ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js

I need to display my users type in a Pie chart.
I am using Angular2, Chart.js and ng2-charts.

**dashboard.component.ts:**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    employees = {}; 
    public countFree : number = 0;
    public countPaid : number = 0;
    public chartData: Array<Object> = [];
    public chartLabels: Array<Object> = [];

    constructor(private dashboard: DashboardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboard.fetchData('http://localhost:8080/employees').subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach(function (eachObj) {
            if(eachObj.usertype=='Free') 
                this.countFree++;
            else
                this.countPaid++;
        }.bind(this));
        this.chartLabels = ['Paid Users', 'Free Users'];
        this.chartData = [{ data: [this.countPaid, this.countFree++] }];
    });
}
```

}

**dashboard.component.html:**

```
<div style="width: 40%;">
 <canvas
   baseChart
   [chartType]="'pie'"
   [datasets]="chartData"
   [labels]="chartLabels"
   [options]="chartOptions"
   [legend]="true"
  </canvas>
</div>
```

I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".
If I place the chart code outside the fetchData(), it works fine.
But I need countFree and countPaid to be showed as chart data.

Need someones help.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution, but you could try this:

```
<div style="width: 40%;" *ngIf="chartData">
 <canvas
   baseChart
   [chartType]="'pie'"
   [datasets]="chartData"
   [labels]="chartLabels"
   [options]="chartOptions"
   [legend]="true"
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first need to make sure that the ng2-charts library and the Chart.js library is added as a dependency:

```
 npm install ng2-charts
 npm install chart.js
```

Make use of ng2-charts directives in our Angular application we need to make sure to add ChartsModule. Therefore first add the following import statement in app.module.ts:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ChartsModule
  ],
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="panel panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h4>Pie Chart</h4>
          <div style="display: block">
            <canvas baseChart
                    [data]="pieChartData"
                    [labels]="pieChartLabels"
                    [chartType]="pieChartType"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  public pieChartLabels = ['Male', 'Female'];
  public pieChartData = [60, 40];
  public pieChartType = 'pie';
}
```

hope this will work for you